# Call to a member function format() on boolean?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a symfony 3 project.  I am trying to post several pieces of information including two dates.  The method looks like this:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/LegoPieces")
 * @METHOD("POST")
 * @View()
 *
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="piece", nullable=false, description="piece"
 * )
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="type", nullable=false, description="type"
 * )
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="startDate", nullable=false, description="Start Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (Should be in the future)"
 * )
 * @Annotations\QueryParam(
 * name="endDate", nullable=false, description="End Date YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS (Should be no more than 3 weeks in the future)"
 * )
 */
public function postAction(ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    $piece = $paramFetcher->get('piece');
    $type = $paramFetcher->get('type');
    $start = $paramFetcher->get('startDate');
    $end   = $paramFetcher->get('endDate');
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(' Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
    var_dump($startDate);
    $endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(' Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');

    $data = new LegoPieces();
    $data->setPiece($piece);
    $data->setType($type);
    $data->setStartDate($startDate);
    $data->setEndDate($endDate);
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse("LegoPieces Added Successfully", 200);
}
```

The setters look like this:

```
        /**
  * Set startDate
  *
  * @param \DateTime $startDate
  *
  * @return LegoPiece
  */
  public function setStartDate($startDate)
  {
   $this->startDate = $startDate;

   return $this;
  }
```

However every time I try to post the data I get the following error message:

```
 "message": "Call to a member function format() on boolean",
            "class": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
```

I've tried everything and nothing works!  Grateful for your help!

Comment: There's no call to `format()` anywhere in the code you posted. Are you sure that's where the error is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the dates you pass into. The problem is most likely from your usage of

```
DateTime::createFromFormat()
```

As the documentation says:

> Returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure.

So, most likely the call fails, returns `false` and later on (probably in your template) you (or Twig when rendering the date) call `format()` on `$startDate` or `$endDate` but one of them is actually not a valid DateTime-object.

My assumption is that the format `' Y-m-d H:i:s'` is not correct, due to the initial whitespace?

Comment: As a side note: You can use type hints in your setter to prevent this from happening or rather your code failing earlier, because PHP will notice that you pass a boolean instead of a DateTime into `setStartDate(\DateTime $startDate)`

Comment: Hi thanks for your help!  I've removed the whitespace but nothing changes - and I get an error message when I add \Datetime before $startDate.  Thanks again!

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you write `$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);` and what is the value of `$start`? Same for the end date?

Comment: I get the same error!  And $start is 2017-12-22 13:26:47 . Thanks!

Comment: good answer mate - i had a date like ' 3-08-18' and it was throwing same error - helped me to solve my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of the problem is same as @dbrumann said. But try creating your date using $startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat() method. When the function cannot create a date from the format, it will return false, and your setter is trying to set the false into the datetime object.